# Python Regexp неправильное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задача гласит:

> Текстовый файл содержит только заглавные буквы латинского алфавита
> (ABC…Z). Определите количество групп из идущих подряд не менее 12
> символов, которые начинаются и заканчиваются буквой E и не содержат
> других букв E (кроме первой и последней) и букв F.
>
> Для выполнения этого задания следует написать программу. Ниже приведён
> файл, который необходимо обработать с помощью данного алгоритма.

[Ссылка на файл онклик](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/get_file?id=114004)

Написал код:

```
import re

with open("24.txt") as file:
    readyLines = re.findall("E[^FE]*E", file.readline())
    print(len(readyLines))
```

Ответ (14100) не совпадает с правильным (9655)
Неправильная регулярка?

**UPD1:**

Итак, благодаря комментариям стало понятно, что способ, который я использовал (Помимо, ошибочной регулярки) был неверным.
 <s>Фильтрация по длине, даже с регуляркой 

**"E[^FE]*(?=E)"** была бы неверной. Поскольку, как и указал мистер @CrazyElf , не отберёт все необходимые выражения.</s> (UPD2)

Но основной ошибкой было неиспользование "[lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)"
(?=...), позволяющей не "забывать" использовать E как начало новой подстроки.

Итоговый, работающий код:

```
import re

with open("24.txt") as file:
    readyLines = re.findall("E[^FE]{10,}(?=E)", file.readline())
    print(len(readyLines))
```

--> 9655

**UPD2:** 
Чтож, фильтрация была бы верной, в отличии от написанного мною в первом апдейте, **но нужно было бы учитывать факт отсутствия последней буквы E**, поэтому код выглядел бы именно так:

```
import re

with open("24.txt") as file:
    readyLines = re.findall("E[^FE]*(?=E)", file.readline())
    print(len([x for x in readyLines if len(x) >= 11]))
```

Comment: А где у вас в выражении условие **идущих подряд не менее 12 символов**? У вас вместо этого квантифаер `*`, означающий совсем другое.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не уточнил в задаче, я далее перебрал список на len() и отобрал те, которые >= 12, ответ всё ещё был другим, видимо ошибка в регулярке

Comment: Отбор потом может не всегда сработать правильно. Например: `EEAAAAAAAAAAE` ваш способ не поймает, потому что найдёт `EE`, а `EAAAAAAAAAAE` уже не найдёт, потому что `EE` он уже откусил.

Comment: Насчёт вашего апдейта. Вот как-раз после добавления `(?=E)` можно и потом по длине фильтровать, и будет работать правильно - можете это сами проверить. Именно "positive lookahead" исправляет с ситуацию с накладывающимися последовательностями. Но лучше, конечно, записать квантифаер на длину последовательности `{10,}` прямо в выражение, зачем двойную работу делать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Кстати, да, но попробовав - я сильно удивился. 
Правильный ответ получается если [x for x in readyLines if len(x) >= **11**] 
Затем я понял, что фактически ведь символа E (Последнего) в строке не остается, а это может НУ ОЧЕНЬ сильно запутать, поэтому единственным верным путём вижу использование квантифаера сразу

Comment: В общем, лучше как-то переформулировать ваше обновление. Или убрать там из выражения `(?=E)`, потому что это всё запутывает и неправильно описывает ситуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ 9655 можно получить, если сделать две вещи:

- правильно написать квантифаер для кол-ва символов с помощью `{...}`
- сделать так, чтобы учитывались и те группы, которые начинаются с того `E`, которым заканчивается предыдущая группа, это делается с помощью "positive lookahead" `(?=...)` для последнего `E`

Второй пункт из текста задания совсем не очевиден, но он позволяет получить правильный ответ.

Comment: Благодарю. Разобрался с выражениями типа (?..), и понял, что количество символов тоже важно использовать в регулярке, а не фильтровать ответы по len, хотя, это оказалось для меня удивительным :)

Comment: Не совсем так, я комметарий под вопросом написал )

Answer (score 1):

В регулярках можно написать `{n,}` - это значит "повторить `n` или более раз".

PS: Я запустил вашу программу с таким выражением, и она вывела `7858`.

Comment: Ну вот зачем вы целиком задание за человека делаете? Надо давать подсказки, а не так сразу. Тем более что да, ответ получается другой. То ли последовательности могут перекрываться, то ли в чём дело - непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, поправил вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, уже с количеством элементов разбираться начал, но в целом - я получил те же самые 7858.

Comment: Вопрос всё ещё открыт, если даже используя {10,} мы получаем неверное значение, хочется найти кейсы, в которых решение не отрабатывает, и понять почему мы их не поймали)